# Customized messages in Google Inactive Account Manager?

Tags: account-management, google-account

Is it possible to send customized message to people when they gain access to my account through the Google Inactive Account manager? If it is not possible, is their anywhere I can go to suggest this feature to Google?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.   You can set up the message content when you set the rules for regarding your account as inactive.